# What is "20/20 Companies ISO Team SmartLink Plus, LLC"? I was given this business card, even after telling him how well I'm doing with another LLC

Tags: software-industry

I've never seen a business card like this, it's so confusing. He was my uber driver and we got to talking about business. Both work for an LLC. I'm a programmer/consulant in healthcare (independent contractor). His card says "20/20 Companies ISO Team SmartLink Plus, LLC", his name with the title of "Director of Operations". What really throws me is the Sprint logo. We connected really well and he was insisting that we should stay in touch, even after telling him how well I was doing with my current LLC. The guy didn't seem shady and really perked up when I told him what I do and provide. I just have never heard of this type of LLC and was wondering if anyone can fill me in, especially for cautions? Said he'll contact me soon.

edit: Sorry, new to here. Not sure how to leave a comment. Anyway, I also sent him an e-mail with a brief description of my experience/skills. The site doesn't exist but I did some reverse DNS retrieval and saw his e-mail uses Gmail. Didn't receive any mail daemon failure when I sent it either. He's looking to start back up after a first LLC failed, "they got too corporate too fast" he explained. I don't know, I'm just a programmer looking to make good money but have to remain skeptic at the same time. I was wondering if this is a known scam.

Comment: can you use the email address to find a website?

Comment: I google "20/20 Companies ISO Team SmartLink Plus" and this question is the first result. Not an encouraging start.

Comment: Note that I would have deleted the bottom left corner of your image (phones and mails) : it gives personnal informations. Even if he gives them to anyone interested.

Comment: It's not great to post someone else's personal information without their knowledge or permission.

Comment: Thanks for removing the picture. I was about to edit/delete it and agree I didn't want to give away personal information, I just saw it as as an advertisement since it was a business card.

Comment: Holy hell.  Sounds like what happens when someone throws a bunch of positive/"professional" sounding terms into a blender and uses what comes out as a company name.  You want to help the guy out, suggest he start by hiring a branding consultant to fix that problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you say “LLC,” we’ll assume you’re likely in the USA.

An Uber driver with grand ideas for starting a business. This is a common story. He formed an LLC with a crazy name and made some business cards. He bought a domain name. Also a common story.

If you are trying to find out if the LLC is legitimate, go to the website of the state government and do a business search for the LLC name. If it’s not found, then the person is either dishonest or clueless, both of which are reasons to avoid doing any sort of business with him.

If you find that he has legitimately started a business, it will be up to you to find out what kind of work he does, whether he needs your services as a software developer, and whether his business is in a position to keep you employed and paid. It’s up to you to decide whether to take the risks associated with a sketchy startup. I say “sketchy” because it’s unlikely he is a good businessman if he is driving for Uber instead of working to get his business off the ground.

EDIT: After seeing the business card, it still seems sketchy. At best, he’s going to be selling cell phone plans on behalf of Sprint, taking a commission. At worst, he just made that stuff up and is using the Sprint logo without authorization. The most likely scenario is that this guy just does a dozen things to earn money, of which driving for Uber and selling cell phone plans are just a couple of them. It is highly unlikely he’ll ever have any work for you. A previous business failing because it “got too corporate too fast” is just blustering on his part.

I just went to the [Illinois Secretary of State website](https://www.ilsos.gov/corporatellc/) and searched for both “20/20” and “SmartLink” and neither search turned up that name from the business card. You can’t just stick a “LLC” on the end of a business name to make it an LLC. It has to be properly registered with the state. Your life will probably be simpler if you just lose that business card and never think about it again.

Comment: Thanks Kent A. I was on the same page with you on everything and completely agree but wanted to get some input. Well said. (A friend was like what? A kiosk at the mall? lol...)

Comment: Other flag the usage of  "ISO". if someone it is not in the company name but at best in a quality of the company (IE : run projects certified ISO 9001)

Comment: @Walfrat There are lots of possibilities for "ISO", but ISO certification is likely not one of them in this instance, given the circumstances. If it is an acronym at all, it might be "In Support Of". Either way, it's a weird thing to put on a business card.

Comment: I'd like to add that a lot of cell phone stores are often contractors working on behalf of cell companies, so that's not entirely uncommon. If there's no Sprint work involved though that's a bad sign.